# how to access the individual elements of a python <class 'requests.models.Response'> class

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, slice

My code accesses a light sensor via a python request:

```
address = 'https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/my_device_id/analogvalue'
headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer {0}'.format(access_token)}
vals = requests.get(address, headers=headers)
```

The code returns the following values:

{"cmd":"VarReturn","name":"analogvalue","result":171,"coreInfo":{"last_app":"","last_heard":"2019-06-13T21:55:57.387Z","connected":true,"last_handshake_at":"2019-06-13T20:51:02.691Z","deviceID":"my_device_id","product_id":6}}

Python tells me that this is a 'requests.models.Response' class and not a dictionary like I thought.

When I try to access the 'result' value, I get error messages. Here are the various ways I have tried along with their error messages.

```
print(vals[2])
```

TypeError: 'Response' object does not support indexing

```
print(vals['result'])
```

TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

```
print(vals[2].json())
```

TypeError: 'Response' object does not support indexing

```
print(vals['result'].json())
```

TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

I got the last two approaches (.json) from a answer here on stack overflow.

Can anyone tell me how to access this result value or am I going to be forced to use regular expression?

EDIT: With help from Sebastien D I added the following and was able to get the result I was looking for.

```
import json
new_vals = json.loads(vals.content)
print(new_vals['result'])
```

Comment: sorry to be dense but how do I use that without getting a NameError: name 'json' is not defined exception?

Comment: see answer below, you just have to import it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do :

```
import json

### your code ###

json.loads(vals.content)
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. I edited my code in the main body to reflect my changes. Thank you.